# Cannot read property 'members' of undefined error

Tags: discord.js

I try to check something and I get an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined
```

The code:

```
module.exports= {
    name: 'roles',
    description: "roles",
    execute(client, message, args){

    let roleID = "754739387295858828";
    let membersWithRole = message.guild.roles.cache.get('754739387295858828').members;
    console.log('sda');
        
    
    }   
}
```

Comment: `message.guild.roles.cache.get('754739387295858828')` returns undefined, double check the role id

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the guild has a role with the provided id before getting the member property.

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'roles',
    description: "roles",
    execute(client, message, args){

    let roleID = "754739387295858828";
    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleID);
    if (role) console.log(`${role.members} member has the role ${role.name}`);
    else console.log(`There's no role with the id ${roleID}`);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi. thanks for helping but it's not working how I want I want to see all the members that have this role

Comment: You can map the role.members property, this should do it `role.members.map((m) => \`${m.displayName} (${m.user.id})\`)`